# Changes in Umbraco CMS does not update at front-end instantly

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, umbraco, asp.net-4.0

I have an issue in updating contents in Umbraco. Whenever I update something in Umbraco, I have to wait at least one hour, sometimes 12 hours to see the changes at front-end.

The only way to see the changes immediately at front-end is "empty the connection string value umbracoDbDSN and refresh the page, then put the connection string back and refresh the page". I have to do everything I update something in CMS.

Do you guys have any idea what is happening here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was. Umbraco was configured to run on load balanced servers on our old servers. I had to turn it off on the new server.

`<distributedCall enable="false">` in `umbracoSettings.config`

Answer (score 1):

What version are you running? When v5 first came out, I had a big problem with that (and solved it like you by touching the web.config to force a reset. Hopefully you are not using v5 (as its been discontinued and has extreme performance issues).

I have not had that problem in any v4.x versions that I can remember; changes should show up instantly after you republish.

Are you running in a standard configuration? Using a webfarm by anyt chance?

Comment: I am using umbraco v 4.7.0. We did not have that problem when the site was hosted on the old server and we keep having this problem since we moved to a new server since we took over the whole site developed by another team.

Answer (score 1):

Is the ~/App_Data/umbraco.config file being written to on publish? This is the XML cache file that is used in displaying you website.

When you publish a node, the data is serialized into XML, stored in a database table and then written out to the umbraco.config cache.

This could be some kind of permissions issue, if umbraco doesn't have rights to read/write the file. Or you could have a corrupt dll that just isn't writing to it correctly. Or perhaps it's writing it out just fine, but your server is caching you pages in a weird way. Either way, I'd take a look first at the umbraco.config and make sure the data is being written to it on publish.

Comment: thanks man. I just checked ~/App_Data/umbraco.config file. There is nothing written in there. I gave IIS_IUSRS full permission to that file and App_Data folder and I tried to publish content in umbraco again. Nothing was written or the front-end update still has problem. :(

Comment: Dude. You are a genius. After giving full permissions IIS_IUSRS and NETWORK SERVICE to umbraco.config and App_Data folder, I tried to unpublish the content and publish it agian. It worked. Then I changed something again and publish again. It worked again. Thanks mate. It's all been solved.